# Read php echo in android program not working

Tags: java, php, android, html, post

I'm trying to read at php echo and store it in a string from an android app, cant seem to get it to work. No errors are given, everything works fine when the code is runned in eclipse but for some reason it wont work in android studio, thought maybe someone here could take a look at it and see if i'm missing something!

```
String login_url = "some url";
    String result="";
    try{



        URL url = new URL(login_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("namn","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(,"UTF-8");


        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        Log.d("HTTPSENDER",""+httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();




        // LÄSER FRÅN HEMSIDAN

        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));

        String line="";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

            System.out.println(result);

            result += line;


        }



        //AVSLUTA CONNECTION
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();


    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so i figured that i could store the output in the string named result and then just use it in a textview or something, but it returns null for some reason when being used in android.

And just for the record, i have been looking through older questions like mine but none have given me much help!

Comment: Can you please show me your PHP code  ?

Comment: it's just an empty site where i have written echo "test" @Ankitvadariya

Comment: what seems wierd to me is that it works perfectly fine when used in an eclipse environment @Ankitvadariya

Comment: okay..
Your url is public ? because if you are running wamp server in your local. you need to put online and mare sure your device & your PC in same network

Comment: yep, everything works perfectly fine on every platform i've tried, sql in other php documents works as expected , just this simple string returns null for some reason @Ankitvadariya

Comment: `when the code is runned in eclipse`. You cannot run Android code in Eclipse. What do you mean?

Comment: `but it returns null for some reason`. It is unclear what would be null. Or who returns a null. Please be specific.

Comment: `result += line;`. That should be `result += line + "\n";`.

Comment: this is a java code that is runnable by android (tested and working), and to correct myself, Result remains "" after being runned in the while loop @greenapps

Comment: You will have a catch. Put `result="Exception: " + e.getMessage();` in that catch block.